# zsh (Default PATH?) messed up with mongodb installation

Tags: mongodb, terminal, macos-big-sur

seems to be imposible after hours and hours trying to solve this problem. All my sudo terminal commands are corrupted due to a several path changes, so i ask for help to set the correct environment variables.
Recently I've a failed installation of mongodb, it was my mistake cause the installation was set for mojave and i've changed several times the path (currently in Big Sur).
The problem starts when i created a .bash_profile in my home user folder, with the mongodb installation path after i moved the files .tgz to /usr/local/mongodb.

After i realized that, i note that when i run sudo 'something' in terminal nothing happens. Instead the name of the window in terminal changes from .zsh to 'sudo' 40x60 and nothing happens. This is very bad for me. Appends all of this i've installed the brand new 11.3.1 big sur update and everything crashes sum the fact that every single file is veryfying...can't at least disable gatekeeper via sudo.

In my user home folder i've:

`.bash_profile: -  export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

.zprofile -

`#Setting PATH for Python 3.9 #The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"`

&

.zshrc
`with nothing inside, empty lines.`

Someone could please provide me the correct paths and commands for each of these files.
I'm only want to have sudo commands again.

Comment: Does the `sudo` binary exist in /usr/bin?  If so, what command are you trying to run that fails?

Comment: i just checked, there are two files in bin that starts with su:  sudo 1,2mb(as a linux executable) and su 124kb (also as a linux executable)

Comment: the commands that fails is everything that starts with sudo. enabled root user and runned terminal from there. the same deal. everything is buggin out since last 11.3.1 update specially the verifying... gatekeeper. can't disable it an analyze every single file it's a drag. please help.